# Smooth mosaicking of smaller orthomosaics to form a homogenous mosaic

Tags: erdas-imagine, mosaic, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, pix4d

This image below is generated using Erdas Imagine where I used mosaicpro tool to create a super mosaic of orthomosaics generated using PIX4d

I used following options:

1. Color Balancing
2. Color Dodging
3. Histogram equalisation
4. Feathering in overlaping areas

Is there a way to smooth these results further such as to remove those strips of light green patches?

[image: Mosaicked data]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is noise / offset pixels or unexpected dark or light strips fringing an object.

Data from airborne multispectral or hyperspectral imaging scanners shows a pronounced striping pattern due to varying offsets in the multielement detectors. This effect can be further exacerbated by unfavorable sun angle. These artifacts can be minimized by correcting each scanline to a scene-derived average ( Kruse, 1988).

Use the **Image Interpreter or the Spatial Modeler** to implement algorithms to eliminate striping.The Spatial Modeler editing capabilities allow you to adapt the algorithms to best address the data. The **IMAGINE Radar Interpreter Adjust Brightness** function also corrects some of these problems.

or by using **low pass filter** on the image.

or in fourier analysis try using **perodic noise removal**.

hope it helps.